# limits.conf priorities

Tags: rhel, ulimit

Does a wildcard have priority over an individual limit? In the example below, will the limit for * be applied to all users including **bar** or all users except **bar**?

```
bar             -       nofile          65536

*               -       nofile          16384
root            -       nofile          16384
```

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: more specific rules should take precedence over broader rules.  have you tested to see if that's the case on your system?

Comment: After re-reading the man, it appears, if I understand correctly, that a wildcard is applied to all users not explicitly defined (`[...]the wildcard *, for default entry[...]`) in the limits.conf.

Comment: limits.conf will apply the wildcard to all users, including those explicitly defined elsewhere.  Then it will apply more specific rules after that.  Least specific to most specific, with the most specific rule for each user taking precedence.